# printing numbers with the width of the length of a specific string in Julia

Tags: printf, julia

In Julia, when I want to print a number "4" with the width of 10, I do:

```
@printf("%10d", 4)
```

If I want to set the width as the length of a specific string, for example:

```
mystr = "Hello World"
```

how to change 10 in "%10d" to `length(mystr)`?

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the [Formatting](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Formatting.jl) library:

```
using Formatting
printfmt("{:$(length("Hello World"))d}", 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Julia doesn't have support for runtime format strings. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4248

However, there is a hack listed in that issue. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4248#issuecomment-24196846. Essentially, you write your own printf function that will compile this on the fly:

`printf(fmt::String,args...) = @eval @printf($fmt,$(args...))`

Comment: Calling eval like this will cause the function `printf` to be compiled each time it is called, this would make your program run much slower than necessary, this may not be a desired side effect.

Comment: That's a good point @Chisholm ... You could avoid some of this unnecessary compiling by defining the function only once, after you have figured out the length of your string. ie. ```@eval printf(x) = @printf($fmt,x)``` where ```$fmt``` is your "runtime" format string.